# Turn an existing WordPress Blog in Wordpress MU

Tags: blogs, wordpress

(sorry for the english...)

for a customer, we have to turn his blog (WP 3.6, more than 10K post and 100K comments) on a WordPress MU, only to move three category from the original blog to another blog (like subdomain.domain.com).

When i will activate the MU on the original blog, will i have any bad consequences on the original blog ? Will i loose anything ? Will i have to create the original blog again as an MU blog ?

Or nothing will happend, and i will just have to create my second blog and do whatever i have to do in ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There's a long time since WPMU became [WordPress Multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/multisite/info) -this link is for the Tag Wiki at WordPress Answers, and there you'll find a list of resources to start with Multisite.

> Will I have any bad consequences on the original blog ?

It's very unlikely, but errors can happen, see bellow.

> Will I lose anything?

Everything will remain in place, but having a [backup (and restore) strategy](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Backups) is essential.

> Will I have to create the original blog again as an MU blog?

No, it will be the **Main Site** and all the newly created sites (blogs) will be **Sub-sites**.

> Will just have to create my second blog and do whatever I have to do in?

Yes. And, using the built-in export/import features, you could export all content from the main site  and import on the sub-site. Then, delete or add content as you see fit.